# How does GNU Argp change its behavior if argp_program_bug_address exists or not?

Tags: c, glibc, weak-symbol

GNU Argp (part of glibc, the GNU C library), changes its behavior based on the non-zero existence of various global variables. For example, if I define `argp_program_bug_address` as a non-zero value, it will be used as part of generated `--help` output.

Detecting the difference between zero and non-zero is straightforward. It's not as obvious how Arpg handles that I might or might not define `argp_program_bug_address` at all. If I do not define it, presumably a definition setting it to zero must exist in glibc. Indeed, there appears to be a defintion in [`argp/argp-ba.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=argp/argp-ba.c;h=03e4cdd600c6916c4a2b1296aa6f38eeb54e2b36;hb=HEAD) ([declaration](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=argp/argp.h;h=77d696c65d18ba449f043b8eaf3b2e36447e2efc;hb=HEAD#l401)). But if that's the case, if I define it, that would mean both I and the library defined it, resulting in link errors complaining about the multiple definition.

Weak symbols seem like a solution, but examining the glibc source, I cannot find any evidence that `argp_program_bug_address` or similar variables are defined weakly.

How is this working so that I can define a value that is used without causing a multiple definition error, but it also works if I never define it?

Comment: Experimentation suggests that when dynamically linking, this Just Works, the value defined in the program overrides the value found in the library. If that's what's going on, I'd be interested in whatever documentation exists that defines this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you link to glibc, you're linking with (e.g.) `/usr/lib64/libc.so`.

This is a linker script:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /lib64/libc.so.6 /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

`argp/argp-ba.c` has only a *single* define of:

```
const char *argp_program_bug_address;
```

This definition goes into `/usr/lib64/libc.a` and is a common symbol (`nm` type `C` and `readelf` type `COM`).

So, if you do *not* define it, the symbol ends up in the `.bss` section using the definition from `libc.a:argp-ba.o`.

If you *do* define it, the linker uses *your* definition and the symbol ends up in the `.data` section.